# Inserting data in SQLite android app is hang

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

While I am inserting data in `SQLite` through background process on home screen app is hang. I cant do any button click. After inserting data successfully in `SQLite` app is working fine. So is there any way while inserting data in `SQLite` and I can easily click on button? [I do not want to show progress dialog and inserting data in db silently]

```
public void Auth(final SignIn mSignIn, final String fbId, final String msgId) {
    CustomRequest jsonObjectRequest = new CustomRequest(Request.Method.POST, General.LOGIN, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject jsonObject) {

            Log.e(LOGTAG, "SignIn Response - " + jsonObject.toString());
            try {
                JSONObject jData = jsonObject.getJSONObject(General.DATA);
                String status = jData.getString(General.STATUSCODE);

                if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {

                    // success
                    dbHelper = new DbHelper(activity);
                    if (dbHelper.dbIsOpen()) {

                    } else {
                        dbHelper.open();
                    }
                    authHandleFetchAuthFriendResponse(jData.getJSONObject(General.FRIENDLIST));

                    dbHelper.close();
                }
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                dbHelper.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(LOGTAG, "SignIn Response Exception - " + jsonObject.toString());
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
            Log.e(LOGTAG, "SignIn Error : " + volleyError.toString());
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("deviceMake", General.DEVICEMAKE);
            params.put("deviceId", GiftAMeal.getInstance().getDeviceId());
            params.put("deviceToken", GiftAMeal.getInstance().getDeviceToken());
            params.put("userName", GiftAMeal.getInstance().getUserName());
            params.put("password", GiftAMeal.getInstance().getPassword());

            return params;
        }
    };
```

//Here is for fetching data shortly from server

```
public void authHandleFetchAuthFriendListResponse(JSONArray jsonArray) {

    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        try {
            Friendlist r = new Friendlist(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i));
            dbHelper.createGiftAMealFriendlist(r);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

// Method for inserting data

```
public long createGiftAMealFriendlistNew(Data.Friend fri) {

    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    // Attributes of Friendlist Table
    initialValues.put(friendListId, fri.getFriendListId());
    initialValues.put(fromUserId, fri.getFromUserId());
    initialValues.put(toUserId, fri.getToUserId());
    initialValues.put(facebookSyncFlag, fri.getFacebookSyncFlag());
    initialValues.put(requestStatus, fri.getRequestStatus());
    initialValues.put(requestSentDate, fri.getRequestSendDate());
    initialValues.put(requestAcceptedDate, fri.getRequestAcceptedDate());
    initialValues.put(requestRejectedDate, fri.getRequestRejectedDate());
    initialValues.put(USER_ID, fri.getUSERID());
    initialValues.put(email, fri.getEmail());
    initialValues.put(userName, fri.getUserName());
    initialValues.put(fbID, fri.getFbID());

    long rowid = mDb.insert(GiftAMeal_FRIENDLIST_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    return rowid;
}
```

Comment: Show your code. A Quick solution - You must be processing on MainThread. Use worker thread instead.

Comment: just do SQLITE in background.

Comment: use rectiveX android to do it in background ..

Comment: use async task instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use AsyncTask just like this

```
class InsertDataAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Long> {

        ProgressDialog progressDialog;
        Data.Friend fri;

        InsertDataAsync(Data.Friend fri) {
            this.fri = fri;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            progressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Long doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try {
                return createGiftAMealFriendlistNew(fri);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return 0L;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Long id) {
            super.onPostExecute(id);
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            if (id > 0) {
                //data insert success
            } else {
                //some error occurred
            }

        }
    }
```

And call this class like this

```
new InsertDataAsync(fri).execute();
```

where `fri` is `Data.Friend` reference.

Hope this help you.

Comment: Writing to disk takes a few hundred milliseconds. This can happen in the background without a blocking dialog (instead of freezing) - user doesn't care how or when you do stuff, they want to use the app.

Comment: Rather than async task its better to use Rx to perform task in a worker thread